# Deploy Rest + gRPC server deploy to k8s with ingress

Tags: go, grpc, http2, kubernetes-ingress, grpc-go

I have used a sample gRPC HelloWorld application https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/helloworld. This example is running smoothly in local system.

I want to deploy it to kubernetes with use of Ingress.

Below are my config files.

**service.yaml** - as NodePort

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grpc-scratch
  labels:
    run: grpc-scratch
  annotations:
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/app-protocols: '{"grpc":"HTTP2"}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: grpc
    port: 50051
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 50051
  selector:
    run: example-grpc
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grpc-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/grpc-services: "grpc"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: true
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - xyz.com
      secretName: grpc-secret
  rules:
    - host: xyz.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /grpc
            backend:
              serviceName: grpc
              servicePort: 50051
```

I am unable to make gRPC request to the server with url `xyz.com/grpc`. Getting the error

```
{
  "error": "14 UNAVAILABLE: Name resolution failure"
}
```

If I make request to `xyz.com` the error is

```
{
  "error": "14 UNAVAILABLE: Trying to connect an http1.x server"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your service defines port 8081, but your ingress wants port 50051. Why?

Comment: @MadWombat updated the service. It was different service pointing to diff port.

Comment: @TusharSheth Can you also share you deployment manifest?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2497

Comment: What are you using as an ingress controller?   gke?  nginx? at least something?

Comment: @A_Suh I am using it for gke.

Comment: @TusharSheth then why you are using `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation?

Answer (score 1):

A backend of the ingress object is a combination of service and port names

In your case you have `serviceName: grpc` as a backend while your service's actual name is `name: grpc-scratch`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grpc-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/grpc-services: "grpc"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: true
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - xyz.com
      secretName: grpc-secret
  rules:
    - host: xyz.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /grpc
            backend:
              serviceName: grpc-scratch
              servicePort: grpc
```